# I'll like to use my credit card to top up account

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Can I use my credit card to top up account,

1. Top-up my account for promotion services
2. HMS core service's top-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to top-up your account for promotion services, then HUAWEI Ads allows you to use the postpayment function if you are registered in certain countries or regions

For details , please refer to:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/promotion/credit-0000001194252897

If you are asking for in HMS core service's top-up, Currently, credit card top-up is not available. You can make an offline payment to the bank provided by the HUAWEI Developers console for top-up.
For details , please refer to:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-account-recharge-0000001126625360